# How to make Cognito User Pool Email attribute mutable without destroying the pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml, aws-cli, aws-userpools

After reading the docs and playing around with aws cli I was unable to find a way of updating mutability of email.
Does anyone has something handy to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

From the [user pool settings documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html):

> An administrator with proper AWS account permissions can change the user's email and also mark it as verified.

Just to double check, it **is** `email` and not `username`, right?

> The preferred_username attribute provides users the experience of changing their username, when in fact the actual username value for a user is not changeable.

Comment: Unfortunately CDK doesn't allow to modify mutability on the email after pool has been created. This is limitation imposed by AWS design.